# 2d color plot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data frame with many events, each of them having a timestamp.

I need a 2-dimensional plot of this: x axis represents days, y axis represents the time of a day (e.g. hours), and the number of events in this hour of this day is represented by the color (or maybe another way?) of the corresponding cell.

First I've tried to use

```
     ggplot(events) + 
      geom_jitter(aes(x = round(TimeStamp / (3600*24)), 
                      y = TimeStamp %% (3600*24))),
```

but due to a large number of events (more than 1 million per month) it's possible to see only the fact that there were events during a specific hour, not how many there were (almost all cells are just filled with black). So, the question is - how to create such a plot in R?

Comment: can you give a sample of your data, at least the structure of the events data.frame?

Comment: Events frame has a TimeStamp column (now it's unix timestamp, but can be converted to any other representation), and other columns which are not related to this plot.

Comment: did you try to modify the the transparency of the point (alpha)?

Comment: sorry @agstudy I just saw your comment as I posted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make a hexbin plot:

```
set.seed(42)
events <- data.frame(x=round(rbinom(1000,1000, 0.1)),y=round(rnorm(1000,10,3)))
library(ggplot2)
library(hexbin)
p1 <- ggplot(events,aes(x,y)) + geom_hex()
print(p1)
```

[image: hexbin plot]

Comment: And a small question - how to change the colors? It seems better to have cells with higher values red, and I can't find how to do this.

Comment: @chersanya Add `+ scale_fill_gradientn(colours=c("blue","red"))` (adjusted to your liking).

Answer (score 2):

The way I'm doing is using a small alpha (i. e. transparency) for each event so that superimposing events have an higher (cumulated) alpha, giving thus an idea of the number of superimposed events:

```
library(ggplot2)
events <- data.frame(x=round(rbinom(1000,1000, 0.1)),y=round(rnorm(1000,10,3)))
ggplot(events)
+ geom_point(aes(x=x, y=y), colour="black", alpha=0.2)
```

[image]

Another solution would be to represent it as an heatmap:

```
 hm <- table(events)
 xhm <- as.numeric(rownames(hm))
 yhm <- as.numeric(colnames(hm))
 image(xhm,yhm,hm)
```

[image]

Comment: Now I've tried this, it works, but very slowly (again, because of tens millions of observations, and each of them corresponds to a point on the graph). Also I remember that somewhere I saw nice plots of this kind where the number of observations in each cell was represented with colors (like heat), but don't remember the name of such plots to search for them.